# How to get path and file name of a pasted image?

Tags: image

Under "Examples" in the help docs for [`ImageData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageData.html) you can see an image of a planetary body (Mars?). The image probably comes from Mathematica's image samples somewhere in its folders. What I mean however is:

How can I get this info right from the cell in the help documentation notebook?

Can one obtain the file source for this image from this expression in the documentation?

Comment: What happens if you choose the Cell > Show Expression menu item with your cursor in the cell? I think it shows that the image is coded into the notebook but I might be wrong...

Comment: As cormullion notes, the image is itself embedded into the notebook. If you use `InputForm[]` to peer at it, you'll see it's an `Image[]` object.

Comment: (It could be [this photo](http://science.nationalgeographic.com/wallpaper/science/photos/mars/mars-earth-hubble/) of Mars, by the way.)

Answer (score 5):

The image "container" or object has several pieces of metadata about the image and its encoding, as well as the image data (i.e., the values that define the pixels) itself. You can see what this data is using

```
InputForm[img]
```

where `img` is your image. For the Mars picture of the question

[image]

this gives:

```
Image[RawArray["Byte", {{{221, 139, 66}, {217, 135, 64} ....
   .... {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}}], "Byte", ColorSpace -> "RGB", 
        ImageSize -> All, Interleaving -> True]
```

so you can see that the meta data is limited to `Byte` type (binary, grayscale, etc) `ColorSpace` (RGB, HSB, etc), `ImageSize`, and `InterLeaving`. There is no place to store an address for the source of the image.

This image of Mars does not seem to be part of the Wolfram curated data, as it is not part of either `ExampleData["TestImage"]` or `ExampleData["AerialImage"].` If you do a google image search on this image, here are the images google thinks are most similar:

[image]

Comment: Love the last 'similar image'!

Comment: [TinEye](http://www.tineye.com/) seems to give more results related to the given image.